# How to give hints to make better edits?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

There is a guy who needs some hints on how to improve posts.

- he makes very small edits by only adding some code formatting
- he applies code formatting to keywords which aren't code
- he doesn't remove smalltalk like "thanks in advance" (and doesn't improve spelling although that might be because he is not a native english speaker)

I actually approved and edited some of his edits, because I didn't realize that there was a pattern. How could I tell him, what he should improve?

Comment: Only 49 rep to go and he can vandalize posts without review!

Answer (score 4):

You can comment on those posts, if you want.  That's pretty much the only form of communication available to you.

Comment: But there it isn't sure the guy will ever see them. You would have to comment on some of his posts, not posts he edited for him to get a notification. Or can I just notify anyone. Trying it... @Chris

Comment: @Trilarion You can notified editors of a post.  You cannot notify just anyone.  You wouldn't need to go find one of his posts.

Comment: He was very active so I found a post which he edited and commented. But it doesn't look right to write a comment to a random post, which isn't related to the post but an user.

Comment: @Chris Ideally the edits should be rejected if they're not appropriate, if they're not, then that's really the larger concern.  If you notice habitual problems with bad edits, or particularly problematic edits being made, you can consider flagging for moderator attention.